# Highcharts - Why does IE9 ignore container width?

Tags: highcharts

As usual Internet Explorer 9 appears to cause problems by ignoring a container `div`'s width and height.

Example:

```
<div id="container" style="width: 50%; height: 400px"></div>
```

Chrome draws a graph inside the container with 50% width and 400px height.
IE9 ignores the container and fills the whole page.

Is this a known issue?

Do I have to explicitly set the width/height on each chart in JSON for IE?

Comment: Could you reproduce issue on jsFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue.

I was upgrading from highcharts 2.2.3 and it appears in later versions having prototype loading on the same page affect IE. As soon as I removed prototype, IE functioned correctly.

Chrome and FF were not affected by prototype.